# What's the difference between Tabular and Power Pivot Mode on SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powerpivot

Previously, we ran SQL Server Analysis Services in Tabular Mode (instead of Multidimensional mode) so that we could import Power Pivot Excel Workbooks and serve them. Installing SQL Server 2014, I see a new option for Power Pivot Mode. How does this differ from Tabular?

Answer (score 1):

Tabular allows you to serve up tabular models, whether you created them from scratch or upgraded them from a Power Pivot model. Tabular models are very similar to Power Pivot models but they have more features (partitioning, security, etc.) and can be larger due to being hosted on a server with more resources rather than inside of Excel.

The Power Pivot mode [specifies Analysis Services instances that were installed as part of a PowerPivot for SharePoint deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471594.aspx). Do not change the deployment mode property of Analysis Services instance that is part of a [PowerPivot for SharePoint installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219067.aspx). PowerPivot data will no longer run on the server if you change the mode.